# issues with Parse framework and iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, parse-platform

I'm trying to integrate Parse framework in my project built in iOS 7. I done in another project with iOS 6 and there wasn't any problem. With the new iOS, the project doesn't compile. It seems that the problem is Parsse framework isn't built for armv7s architecture. I don't know how to solve this problem.

**I attach the problems that xcode 5 shows:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s: "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:

  _initializeStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:

  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:

  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:

  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:

  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _readEntriesFromDatabase:excludingFragment:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:

  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:

  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_step", referenced from:

  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _dropTrimmingTable] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  ...
"_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:

  _initializeStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:

  ___39-[PF_FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:

  _releaseStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  _initializeStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _readEntriesFromDatabase:excludingFragment:] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[PF_FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
  ...
"_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:

  _releaseStatement in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_close", referenced from:

  ___26-[PF_FBCacheIndex dealloc]_block_invoke in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
"_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:

  ___39-[PF_FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke in Parse(PF_FBCacheIndex.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem: what worked for me was to include the libraries:

```
libsqlite.3dylib
libz.dylib
```

They can be found in the Parse PushNotificationTutorial project. You can download it from the web of Parse.